# Como enviar e receber dados para BD MySQL usando PHP em Objective-C?

Tags: php, mysql, json, objective-c, post

Cenário: 
 Enviar e receber formulários para um banco de dados MySQL usando PHP.

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe ou tem algum link para um tutorial didático e claro sobre esses procedimentos, de envio e recebimento usando JSON.

Pode ser em inglês ou português, e preferência para a transferência Assíncrona.

Comment: Onde entra o "Objective-c" da pergunta?

Comment: O Objective-C entra no meu trabalho de elaborar uma atividade com web service e PHP no meu projeto! Não entendi o pq da tua negativação, se não entendeu não precisa negativar, basta fazer um comentário.

Comment: Tiago, a gente não tem como saber quem negativos, pode não ter sido ele.

Comment: Ah nao, tranquilo, não estou acusando ele, na verdade são duas respostas em um comentário, como o sistema remove as linhas vazias, não separou as frases. :D

Comment: Tenta isso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x47niEJk_M

Comment: Kkkkk muito bom!!! A cara do Jason no splash do video!!!@touchmx

Comment: Encontrei outro video muito bom e ja construi o codigo ( PHP e Objective-c), vou postar pra galera aqui!!! Mas obrigado assim mesmo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi essa! Posso enviar um argumento para um php e ele me retorna o resultado da query:

```
// FUNCIONA PODE SER USADO PARA ENVIAR OS ARGUEMENTOS E RECEBER O RETORNO DA QUERY DO PHP

    NSMutableString* strURL =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/testesPHP/buscaFuncionarios.php?numero=%@",nomeCadastro.text];


    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: strURL];


    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError*erro;

    NSMutableArray* oabsRecebidas;

// Recebe o retorno vindo do arquivo PHP buscaFuncionarios.php (no caso usando Json)
    oabsRecebidas = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&erro];

// Escreve na tela o retorno
    NSLog(@"%@", oabsRecebidas);
```